# How to add a JSON object / model into your whitestorm.js world / scene?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am loading the object from my json file.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("blue-car.json",
function ( car ) {
  car.position.set(2, 0, 0);
  car.addTo(world);
 }
);
```

And this is the error...
[image]
How can I add the object to my world? In regular three.js it works when I load the json file, but how do I do it in whitestorm?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking to documentation?

Use this sample code:

```
// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

// load a resource

loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'models/animated/monster/monster.js',
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( object );
    }
);
```

Comment: So if I use the JSON loader it throws an error that I should use the ObjectLoader method instead. My problem is importing the object into a whitestorm world. In plain three.js it works but I can't get it in whitestorm. I tried also importScene method in whitestorm. It did not give me errors but it still does not show in the scene.